# NLogViewer UDP target remains silent in Azure Service Classic

Tags: azure, logging, service, udp, nlog

I have a classic Azure Cloud Service. I'd like to integrate its logging capabilities with NLog.

It works great with AzureBlobStorage target, it logs to logfiles as expected.

I also would like to add NLogViewer UDP target in my NLog config file:

```
<target xsi:type="NLogViewer"
               name="udpviewer"
               address="udp://x.y.z.1:12345" />
```

I used this several times in my Windows Services without any problem, but in Azure service I can not make it work, it remains silent, I don't get any log entries via UDP. I start to think it is not supported in Azure Services? Or does it have any config to set to make it work? Or?

Any help is highly appriciated!

Comment: have you tried to integrate NLog with Application Insights? It should be the best way to do this, or replace the way your application logs just using AI?

Comment: I need NLog with Log4View, its a must in the project.

Comment: UDP protocol is not supported for NFS 3.0 currently in blobs. Using a VM for this can be a security DRDoS breach. So you should rethink this i guess.

Comment: Did you try to telnet from Azure Cloud Service to x.y.z.1:12345?